# create version of row entry on every update table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i had a table **FOO** and on every update of this (i.e: according to some buisness logic) it should create a version of the entry. how to create a schema(table schema to store versions of that particular row entry) that can create a version of every update row on **FOO** table that reference **FOO** table entry

Comment: VIa a trigger..

Comment: @P.Salmon want to know how to create a table that stores the versions

Comment: Can you be more specific, CREATE TABLE  creates tables an audit/log table could be the same as FOO with added bits..depends what you want to log(before and after image for all of foo, just the columns that have changed etc) , date updated, whodunnit - really up to you and the business logic.

Comment: Read up on triggers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger and google around this topic,and for mysql specific this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Are you looking for [system versioned tables?](https://www.google.com/search?q=system+versioned+tables+mysql&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=system+versioned+tables+mysql&aqs=chrome..69i57.7895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: See MariaDB for this feature.